# How to get T object from generic interface in c#

Tags: c#, generics

```
    abstract class Point2D
    {
        public virtual string X { get; set; }
    }

    abstract class Point3D
    {
        public virtual string X { get; set; }
        public virtual string Y { get; set; }
    }

    interface IPoint3D<T>
    {
         T GetT();
    }

    class Point : Point2D, IPoint3D<Point3D>
    {

        public Point2D GetPoint2D()
        {
         return this;
        }

        public Point3D GetT()
        {
            return null; // how to return point3D?
        }
    }
```

I am having two abstract class and i am trying to inherit them into another class. how to get Point3D object from IPoint3D interface?

is there any work around to do multiple inheritance ?

Comment: Except an instance of `Point` *isn't* an instance of `Point3D`. C# just doesn't support multiple inheritance of classes like this.

Comment: What do a `Point3D` and a `Point2D` have in common? There is no relation between those two.

Comment: If you really want a `Point3D` from that method, then can you not create a `Point3D` instance in that method, set property `X` and return it?

Comment: is there any work around to do multiple inheritance ?

Comment: Not in C#, Like Himbrom said, there is not relation between those.

Comment: Why not implement several interfaces instead of having "proper" multiple inheritance?

Comment: Why don't you just make point3d inherit from point2d?

Comment: Why aren't `Point3D` and `Point2D` types of `Point`?  Just by the naming they sound like specific implementations of point.

Comment: You seem to have an XY-problem. Your code does weird things because your logic does weird things. A point in 3D space is not a point in 2D space. You can project a point in 3D space onto a 2d space, but that's not a simple, no-parameters operation. At least you'd need the definition of the 2D space in 3d coordinates.

Comment: @nvoigt the above class is just an example. We have pinvoke operations on the abstract classes that cannot be made into interfaces.

Comment: Don't use a bad example, show what you really need to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can solve this by simple inheritance:

```
abstract class Point2D
{
    public virtual string X { get; set; }
}

abstract class Point3D : Point2D
{
    public virtual string Y { get; set; }
}

class Point : Point3D
{
    // does not need extra function, this *is* a Point2D AND a Point3D
}
```

I still hope this is an example, because a point in 2D space is **not** a point in 3D space with one coordinate ignored... and more upsetting, a point in 2D space would need 2 coordinates, X and Y, not just one. But this is the syntax to do it.

Your P/Invoke methods should be in *neither* class. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434338/best-practices-for-organizing-net-p-invoke-code-to-win32-apis) for best practices.